# driver.findElement(...).clear() not successful in clearing the input file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, junit

The following statement is not working

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='From']")).clear();
```

The field is not cleared as you can see in the following screenshot below. It is successfully located since the next string is input so it should normallky be sucessful in clearing the field. I would like CASABLANCA-Mohammed V to be deleted and be replaced by RBA. How to fix this?

[image]

```
package Test;
// Generated by Selenium IDE
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.After;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsNot.not;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
public class AirLineTest {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private Map<String, Object> vars;
  JavascriptExecutor js;
  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    vars = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  }
  @After
  public void tearDown() {
    driver.quit();
  }
  @Test
  public void test() {
   
    driver.get("https://www.lufthansa.com/ma/en/homepage");
    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1552, 840));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"cm-acceptAll\"]")).click(); 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='From']")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='From']")).sendKeys("RBA"); 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='To']")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='To']")).sendKeys("JFK"); 
    driver.close(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: first _click_, then _clear_ and finally _sendKeys_

Comment: I did that and then after clicking on it again after clearing it, it is automatically filled in with the value "Casablanca" again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to do it with java but on python that code works fine :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import selenium.webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

chrome_options = selenium.webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)  
driver.get("https://www.lufthansa.com/ma/en/homepage")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
driver.find_element('xpath',"//input[@placeholder='From']").send_keys('')
actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('A').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
actions.send_keys(Keys.DELETE).perform()
# Your Code here
```